# Cannot use dataclassesdatacontext

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a website wich runs like a charm locally, but when i take it online it cannot find the dbml, i have imported the dbml class but it says:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'DataClassesDataContext' is not defined.

Source Error:

Line 201:        Dim dc As New DataClassesDataContext
```

And i have uploaded my .dbml file to the server.
I have some experience of linq before and this has never happened before

I dont understand why its doing this... I rechecked on my webserver, and the correct .net version was installed. but it works locally so it must be problems on the webserver. but what?

I've checked with the web-host and theres nothing wrong with the .net version.. Dunno really what could be the problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by generating new dbml files like 5 times, also by changing the .net verion of the webserver to the same version i had. Also rebuild the project and upload it some more times... never figured out what the reason was